# Trying to center images in Boostrap image carousel on Google Sites

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, sites

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGown.jpg)

Trying to fix the code so the six images in this Bootstrap Carousel all show centred on my (new version) of Google sites, instead of being pushed to the top, like in the screenshot. Would be so grateful. Code is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSvl1JW8T3I1LmE-UKhotNVDlRtqBNAnzytD2LmTpb5Y82tryrP8Qq5ZM2ITlYtfEUo9BV-qOO3kepQ/pub)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] first. Remember to __add code as text__ and __embed images__ using `![description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGown.jpg)`. So we can quickly see, copy and solve.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- the images in your carousel have a brown-goldish bar under the grey border, which would throw off the visitor... so you may need to crop the images
- I replaced the background for the container class with the color pink so that it becomes easier for us to check the spacing around the image
- I added a 2% bottom so that we can see the pink background and you can adjust as per your requirement

**working snippet**:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 2%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <a href="http://www.ashdownhouse.com">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1HIkliSgbwTyE2jm0VTKovz-0sL-MvtY5" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="http://www.barfieldschool.com">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1D6CYYSJ5RmFTss_Uwtz26Yp4iDbzjPGx" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="http://www.chandlings.org.uk">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1sjJbhxr-BlqGFMynCwvoyjxsv9QgizKi" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="http://www.cothill.net">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1_uoO1czc3U1y-Yzl7Bl6-Ue7LhgcX8HL" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="http://www.kitebrookhouse.com">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17l0qy3JT6tt_O-fte7P11nMipqifhvg2" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="http://www.mowdenhall.co.uk">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1XFeNIUl1ZoWq1Ph_6siVM0bV0yxf0X3P" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="http://www.sauveterre.net">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=10XrCAUh9c4RSnoD0pjkdNl0PXV0whST2" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```